# Copy data to clipboard does not work properly

Tags: reactjs

I try to copy data to clipboard in react js using this code:

```js
const itemToBeCopied = "Hello CodeSandbox";

export default function App() {
  const copyData = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(itemToBeCopied).then(
      function () {
        alert("succes copied");
      },
      function (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={copyData}>Copy</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Clicking on the button i don't get the copied variable to the clipboard and i don't understand why.
Why i ca not copy that string into the clipboard and how to solve the issue?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/copy-to-clipboard-js-forked-slcym?file=/src/App.js:51-441

Answer (score -1):

If you `console.log(e.message)` you will see the following error:

> The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied
> to the current document. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes for more details.

Obviously, there is some issue with sandbox. Your code seems to be fine.